# How to display UINavigationController with Back button

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.1

I have a UITableViewControoler, I display it using below code. It works fine, except i don't see the back button:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    UITableViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FindLandTableIdentifier"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:svc];


    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a back button until you push another controller onto the navigation controller's stack, and you're currently in that second (or beyond) controller's view. A back button is for popping controllers off the navigation controller's stack, not for undoing a modal presentation.

Comment: @user836026, instantiate a new controller and call pushViewController:animated: on the navigation controller. But that's not going to get you a back button that will go back from the modal presentation you did, if that's what your after.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the view controller you are navigating from and click drag to the next view controller and select push to create one using storyboards. Also check the navigation controller that your view controller is embedded in has Navigation Bar turned on otherwise it won't show.